# colorbox - ajax get a div or section

Tags: jquery, ajax, selector, colorbox

I am loading up an page on my page with the ajax colorbox call. At the moment I am just using

```
$('.ajax').colorbox();
```

I thought I may be able to do something like

```
$('.ajax#content').colorbox();
```

How can I pull an portion of my page by passing the selector?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean passing a variable into your selector? in which case that would be something like:

```
var myVariable = 'test'; //Your variable goes here

$('.ajax#' + myVariable).colorbox();
```